# Is there any way to launch an interactive CLI application in the background? (with &)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I have a superwide monitor and I enjoy having `bpytop` running on my screen at all times next to my browser.

Unfortunately, there is no way to automatically change the color scheme of a running `bpytop` instance, so when I run my glorious day/night mode script, `bpytop` sticks out like a sore thumb.

I want to work around that by automatically restarting `bpytop` when its config file changes. This sounds relatively simple in theory:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Wrapper for bpytop that restarts when the config file changes on disk
#

CONFIG_FILE="$HOME/.config/bpytop/bpytop.conf"

trap "kill $BPYTOP_PID &>/dev/null" EXIT

while true; do
    bpytop &
    BPYTOP_PID=$!

    inotifywait -e modify "$CONFIG_FILE"

    kill "$BPYTOP_PID"
done
```

Unfortunately again, `bpytop` doesn't really like being launched in the background like that, probably because STDIN isn't being hooked up to the parent shell STDIN:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bpytop", line 5667, in 
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/bpytop", line 5547, in main
    Term.echo(False)
  File "/usr/bin/bpytop", line 722, in echo
    (iflag, oflag, cflag, lflag, ispeed, ospeed, cc) = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin.fileno())
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

Is there any way to forward the STDIN pipe of the current shell to applications running in the background?

Comment: Is this a suplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208003/run-two-programs-in-while-keeping-stdin-of-the-first-connected/70208193#70208193 ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Good question. The answers definitely overlap, but the questions are asked very differently. I'm not sure if anybody Googling my problem would find that other question.

Answer (score 0):

The STDIN file descriptor of the current process can be found at the special path `/proc/self/fd/0`. You can use input redirection (`<`) to use this file descriptor as STDIN for the child process.

Here's a working implementation of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Wrapper for bpytop that restarts when the config file changes on disk
#

CONFIG_FILE="$HOME/.config/bpytop/bpytop.conf"

trap "kill $BPYTOP_PID &>/dev/null" EXIT

while true; do
    bpytop < /proc/self/fd/0 &
    BPYTOP_PID=$!

    inotifywait -e modify "$CONFIG_FILE"

    kill "$BPYTOP_PID"
done
```

This should work with any interactive terminal application.

You could also use `/dev/stdin`, which is a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/0`, or you could simply use `&0`, which is special syntax for "my own STDIN", at least in bash and zsh. For example:

```
bpytop <&0 &
```

---

*I discovered the answer to this question while writing it, but I thought I'd post it anyway as it might be useful for somebody else.*

Comment: I would imagine you could use `/dev/stdin` instead?

Comment: Just `<&0`. `an be found at the special path` _on linux_. I do not think it's universal for unix-es, but maybe it is, I'm not sure.

Comment: @AndreasLouv Yep, also `&0` works, which is syntax I've never seen before researching this issue . I've edited the answer to include those.

Comment: `bash` allows `/dev/stdin` in a *redirection* regardless of whether the path actually exists in the file system.